# Questions regarding highcharts behavior

Tags: angular, highcharts

First of all, here is a stackblitz of an application that will demonstrate the behavior I am questioning in this post: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mlqro1?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts

**First question:** When you click the button `Add object to array`, 6 charts will be created. There will be data added to the chart using the `setData()` method:

```
chart.series[0].setData(chartData, false);
```

Since i passed the argument `false`, the data points should not be drawn on the chart yet. The result of this is that the first chart is empty, while the 5 other charts have their data points drawn. This is unexpected behavior, but my theory is that the data points are automatically drawn on a chart when it has been rendered. So the last 5 charts are rendered AFTER I have called `setData(data, false)` on them, and the first one is rendered before. Could that explain it?

**Second question:** After the charts have been created, an update method that updates each chart will run every 10 seconds. The method adds 6 random numbers from 1-100 to each of 6 data containers - one for each chart. It will then find the correct data container for the given chart (assigned to `chartData` object), change whatever the last value was to 55 and set the data on the chart.

The result of this is that all points change each update except the last one, but it's only the first (and second?) chart where the value of the last point is actually 55. When i console.log the data container arrays for each chart the last value of all of them is 55, but it's only displayed on the first chart. It seems that after the first chart gets its last value set to 55, the remaining charts think their last point is also 55 and therefore do not update it.

Hopefully someone can help me make sense of this. Thanks!

**EDIT:** Regarding question 2, I've discovered that if I call `setData()` with the `updatePoints` boolean parameter set to false, like so:

```
series.setData(chartData,false, true, false);
```

Then it works - last value of all charts is 55. So it seems like there is a problem with `updatePoints` ?

Comment: The issues you have are all concerned with mutating the options of the charts instead of creating a fresh options object. Highcharts mutates the options so you should never share/reuse options, data, etc. between charts. I have simplified your live demo to let you see the the point cleaner - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7ek5ze?file=app/app.component.ts. Run the demo and then uncomment getChartOptions() and run the demo again - you should be able to see the problems when you reuse options and when the options are new for each chart.

Comment: @morganfree Thanks, that makes sense. However, when you bind the options to a method, it causes the `saveLineChart()` method to be called all the time.  (Try putting a console.log() in the method). Isn't that a problem? Like for example if I do it the same way as you in my stackblitz, the app won't work.

Comment: It should be called every time a new chart is created, e.g. when the component is initialised. So on init - you can get new options for the component and then reuse it but only for that specific component.